# JMXMoon ссылка на толковый мануал

Tags: jmeter

Кто использовал JMXMoon Samples Collector, - подскажите что указывать в полях Key,Delta,Retry? Тестирую объект IMAP в hazelcast...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Толковый мануал имеется на вики: [JMXMon Sample Collector](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMXMon/). Можно еще посмотреть [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)

Если аттрибут "простой", например `com.hazelcast:instance=default,type=HazelcastInstance.EventService,name=default` -> `eventThreadCount` - не нужно ничего указывать, достаточно имени аттрибута, который вас интересует.

[image: JMeter JMX Hazelcast]

Если аттрибут более "сложный", например как `java.lang:type=Memory` -> `HeapMemoryUsage` -

[image: JMeter JMX Heap Memory]

То возможные значения ключей можно посмотреть по клику:

[image: JMeter JMX Mon Keys]

В случае с `Delta` листенер будет записывать изменение с предыдущего раза вместо актуального значения аттрибута. `Retry` в объяснениях не нуждается, это просто повтор неудавшегося сбора результата по объекту/аттрибуту.

Все аттрибуты, которые доступны через JMX можно посмотреть при помощи [JConsole](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html)